# Content-md5 error getting returned and i dont know why

Tags: python, roblox

i'm pretty new to api programming and i'm currently stuck due to the Content-md5 not getting submitted properly. I've absolutely no clue how i should start working on it.

The api i'm trying to request is the newly published [Datastore API](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/open-cloud-data-store-api-reference/1736533#heading--get-entry) from roblox.

```
headers = {'x-api-key' : API_KEY, 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
params={"datastoreName" : "AmountDonatedStore", "entryKey" : str(user.id)+"-xp"}

r = requests.post("https://apis.roblox.com/datastores/v1/universes/3450454946/standard-datastores/datastore/entries/entry", headers=headers, params=params)
```

the error i'm getting is this one:

```
b'{"error":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","message":"Content-md5 header required.","errorDetails":[{"errorDetailType":"DatastoreErrorInfo","datastoreErrorCode":"ContentMd5Required"}]}'
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The API wants you to provide a `content-md5` header, but you didn't...

Comment: what would i need to put into the content-md5 header?

Comment: According to that documentation link, it should be "the base-64 encoded MD5 checksum of the content".